# Oracle Hierarchical Query Connect by Parent Child Tree Unknown level deep?

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchical-data

Oracle Hierarchical Query Connect by Parent Child Tree Unknown level deep?
Simple yet I cannot seem to make it work...

---

```
Table ABC
 ID      parent_ID   Name  
1          0          Art
2          0          Home
3          0          Contact
4          0          Bob
5          0          Boo
6          0          Foo
7          2          FooBoo
8          5          Hoo
9          8          My
10         2          Rob

Order by Name Results wanted
```

---

```
Art
Home
** FooBoo
** Rob
Contact
Bob
Boo
** Hoo
** ** My
Foo
FooBoo
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT NAME, id, parent_id, LEVEL
FROM ABC
START WITH id = 0
CONNECT BY PRIOR id = parent_id
ORDER SIBLINGS BY NAME;
```